# "starting soon" or "started soon"?

Tags: future-tense, future-continuous

I would like to ask which one is the appropriate grammar for using "starting soon" or "started soon".

For example:

> The commissioning will be **starting soon**.

Is this right or wrong?

Comment: Could you clarify your question slightly?  Are you asking about "will be starting soon" versus "will be started soon"?

Answer (score 1):

> The commissioning will be starting soon.

The above statement talks about something that is yet to happen.

> The commissioning started soon.

This statement is narrative of what happened.

Could be written as

> The commissioning started soon after the proposal was accepted.

---

**EDIT**

They are both correct as @HotLicks pointed out.

*will be started* is future perfect tense.
*will be starting* is future continuous tense.

Comment: It's perfectly logical to write "The commissioning will be started soon." or "The commissioning is starting soon."   But "The commissioning started soon." is nonsense, absent any qualification.

Comment: @HotLicks yes you are correct.